# Unable to run the 20newsgroups example for bayes classifier in mahout

Tags: classification, mahout

I am trying to run the 20newsgroups example as mentioned in [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.scm/2851) page. When I generate input data set using this piece of code

`$> $MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.PrepareTwentyNewsgroups \
  -p examples/bin/work/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-train \
  -o examples/bin/work/20news-bydate/bayes-train-input \
  -a org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DefaultAnalyzer \
  -c UTF-8`

all I could get is a warning that states that

> No org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.PrepareTwentyNewsgroups.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only

Is it a bug in mahout itself? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it. Actually the directory examples/bin/work/20news-bydate/bayes-train-input has been created, but my file explorer didn't show it instantly even though I refreshed. Later when I did an ls from the terminal, I was able to see the folders created!